# Selenium Web Driver & C# - Selecting Second <h3> Inside A div

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Visual Studio & C#.

I am testing a web page that contains two  sub-headings within the same div. They are 'User Name' and 'User Location'.
I am able to locate the first h3

```
 Assert.AreEqual("User Name", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='user-details-form']/h3")).Text);
```

But I am unable to get Selenium to find the second one because it always finds the first one.
How can I get it to skip over the first one to find the second one?

Comment: Please share your HTML code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find target element by providing their text as below :-

```
Assert.AreEqual("User Name", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='user-details-form']/h3[contains(text(),'User Name')]")).Text);
```

Hope it will help you to find `User Name` sub heading...:)

Answer (score 0):

I never use XPATH...

```
var h3s = wd.findElements(By.TagName("h3")).Where(p=>p.Text=="SomeValue").ToList();
```

Note: You may have more than one so additional logic is needed for the right one.

Comment: When I try to use this I get an error 'IWebElement does not contain a definition for 'where''

Comment: You have to use LINQ... Are you using C#? Sorry forgot to ask.  Add this to top of file  "Using System.Linq;"

Comment: Yes my question title says C#

Answer (score 0):

XPath is best avoided unless absolutely necessary. In this case, I'd use a css selector to get a collection of all the h3 elements, then you can find the one you want if you know it's position.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("form#user-details-form h3"));
WebElement e = list.get(5);
Assert.AreEqual("User Name", e.Text);
```

Comment: When I try to use this I get errors
'The non generic type 'List' cannot be used with type arguments.'
'The type or namespace WebElement could not be found, are you missing a using directive or an aseembly reference?'

Comment: @Leroy-S use IList instead of List. Your error will be resolved.

Comment: I receive the error ''The type or namespace name IList<WebElement> could not be found, are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: You either have a missing reference in your project, or you need to add a using directive at the top of the page. I cannot remember off the top of my head what the directive is for webelement, but it will be something like `using OpenQA.Selenium;` If that doesn't work then you need to add a reference in the project.